# Water Consumption App

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple calculator. User will click on button and it will calculate the total amount of water he/she drinks on that day. And it also should show a list of time and date for every click.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int baslangic= 0;
float sayac = 0.2f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button ekle = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ekle);
    final TextView toplam = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toplam);
    toplam.setText("" + baslangic);

    ekle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            class SuToplam {
                public void main(String args[]) {
                toplam.setText("" + baslangic);
                for (float sayac= 0.2f; sayac >= 0.2; sayac= +0.2f){
                    sayac ++;
                }
                }
            }




        }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is what am l doing wrong? As the loop is not working and when l click on the button, it is not adding up 0.2 per click.

Comment: You should write the question in your post not in the comments. Be more specific when you ask a question if you want to get some help.

Comment: You create a local variable inside the for loop that has the same name as your member variable. You probably dont want that. Also why do you have a class inside the onClick() method? And what exactly does your for loop try to achieve.